# Detecting keypress in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, keyboard-events

Is there a way to detect keypress **only** when the Google Maps canvas is *in focus*?

Google Maps JavaScript API V3 has built-in keyboard shortcuts. When a user clicks on a map tile or drags it, the map becomes *in focus*, and will respond to keyboard shortcuts. If you click anywhere else outside the map canvas, those keyboard shortcuts will no longer work.

I would like to extend some of these shortcuts (specifically the arrow keys) to perform additional actions.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the keyboard shortcuts in Google Maps like here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MapOptions

and then you can use the keyboard shortcuts for your own purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am looking for a way to **detect keypress _only_ when the Google Maps canvas is in focus**. I want to **extend (NOT disable)** some of the shortcuts to perform **additional actions**.